# Laravel form submit returns error 302, is there something wrong with my route?

Tags: laravel, post, http-status-code-302

I have a form submit with username and password as well as the csrf but upon submitting I suddenly encountered 302.

I'm stuck and did error trappings with the code but nothing helped.

Here's my form

```
<form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="POST" class="login-section">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="devicetype" class="device_type">
    <div style="margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;">Email: <input type="text" name="username" class="userName textboxes push-right-33 form-control-lg" required></div>

    <div style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;">Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="password textboxes form-control-lg" required></div></br>

    <div class="links">
        <button type="submit" class="button">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Sign In
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="button forgot-password">
            <i class="fas fa-recycle"></i> Password Reset
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here's my route

```
Route::post('/signin', 'LoginContoller@authenticateUser')->name('signin');
```

and finally the controller

```
public function authenticateUser(Request $var){

    // echo "string";
    // die();

    $userEmail = $var->input('username');
    $userPass  = $var->input('password');
    $devType   = $var->input('devicetype');

    $timestamp = time();
    $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

    $sessTime = $this->checkTime($userEmail);


    // echo $sessTime;
    // echo $userEmail. "string" . $userPass . "string" . $devType . "string" . $timestamp . "string" . $date_time . "string" . $sessTime;
    // die();
```

where I use use the first die area it stops and shows the word string which means my route is correct and it indeed went in to authenticateUser function but when I use the second die it just reloads the page and shows 302. I'm thinking that it has something to do with this area

```
$userEmail = $var->input('username');
    $userPass  = $var->input('password');
    $devType   = $var->input('devicetype');

    $timestamp = time();
    $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Please check you routes . There should be same route. Or in controller you are redirecting user back to login

Comment: As @NipunTharuksha says, you may have multiple routes pointing to `/signin` or `/signin/{someVar}`. If latter is the case, place your static URLs before dynamic ones.
Make sure checkTime() function is returning correctly (would love if you posted the code here).
Also, are you sending CSRF token in your request?
Lastly, `dd()` does dump your vars and die so you don't have to write `echo` and `die()` all the time.

Comment: Check you the middleware of route's group. If {auth} middleware is implemented to your route group it will redirect